# blueprint How to implement component zooming at the mouse pointer location in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am developing a Flutter widget and I need to implement a feature where the component can be zoomed in or out at the location of the mouse pointer when it hovers over the component. I would like to dynamically adjust the component's zoom level based on the position of the mouse pointer. How can I achieve this functionality in Flutter?

I have tried using InteractiveViewer, but it seems to reset the center.

```
InteractiveViewer(
  transformationController: _transformationController,
  onInteractionUpdate: (details) {
    print("details.scale:${details.scale}");
    var scale = 0.5;
    if (details.scale > 1.0) {
      scale = 1.5;
    }
    _transformationController.value =
        _transformationController.value
          ..translate(
            details.localFocalPoint.dx,
            details.localFocalPoint.dy,
          )
          ..scale(scale)
          ..translate(
            -details.localFocalPoint.dx,
            -details.localFocalPoint.dy,
          );
  },
  minScale: 1,
  maxScale: 50.0,
  child: ValueListenableBuilder<List<INode>>(
    valueListenable: bp.NodeManager,
    builder: (context, value, child) {
      return Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: [
          ...value,
        ],
      );
    },
  ),
)
```

I'm sorry, I only have the image URL
error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKACu.gif

The desired effect I want is to achieve.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl3hT.gif

Are there any components or methods that can achieve this? I would greatly appreciate your help.